# Cann't find "process_cpu_seconds_total" in prometheus UI

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-operator, prometheus-node-exporter

Hello Prometheus Experts,

I am very new in Prometheus. Following some example video, I am trying to learn this tool.

When I am trying "process_cpu_seconds_total" in Prometheus Execute text box, it is not returning any value. What is the issue in my installation?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The likely reason is that your Prometheus does not scrape anything, either because of an error of lack of configutaion. From the web-UI click ***Status -> Targets*** and ***Status -> Configuration***. There you should have some targets to scrape, and the configuration should have some scrape jobs, that define what, where and how to scrape.